# Why does Compounding in Illustrator not behave the same for all paths?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, path

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l8uGl6LdV7Q

Above is a video showing the problem.

How can I create a compound path out of several shapes by pressing the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> just once?

Right now it looks like it compounds 1 shape but merges the other ones.

Answer (score 3):

It has to do with the winding order rule you have configured. You are using the *Non-Zero Winding Fill Rule*, while you anticipate it to work like *Even-Odd Fill Rule* would. You can find this option in the **Window → Attributes** Panel, make sure you expand the panel from hamburger menu with **Show All**.

[image]

**Image 1**: Winding rule and its effect on compound object.